# networkX DiGraph: list all neighbouring nodes disregarding edge direction

Tags: python, networkx

Is there a better way to obtain the list of nodes that connect to a given one in a directed graph via a single edge (whether inbound or outbound)?

Here is what I came up with. First I build and draw a demo DiGraph:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([
    ('A','B'),
    ('B','C'),
    ('C','D'),
    ('D','E'),
    ('F','B'),
    ('B','G'),
    ('B','D'),
])
nx.draw(
    G,
    pos=nx.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot'),
    node_color='#FF0000',
    with_labels=True
)
```

[image: simple demo directed graph]

and now I'd like to get all "neighbouring nodes for node 'B'" and currently I do so with:

```
node= 'B'
incoming = [n for n in G.predecessors(node)]
outgoing = [n for n in G.successors(node)]
neighbours = incoming + outgoing 
print(neighbours)
['A', 'F', 'C', 'G', 'D']
```

Is there a simpler, better, faster way of achieving this result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use networkx inbuilt methods instead

```
from networkx import*
list(all_neighbors(G, 'B'))
['A', 'C', 'G', 'D', 'F']
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for: a library function Thanks a bunch and happy winter holidays!!!

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of the class `nx.DiGraph`

> the edges reporting object is often more convenient:

```
>>> for u, v, weight in G.edges(data="weight"):
...     if weight is not None:
...         # Do something useful with the edges
...         pass
```

What you want can be achieved using `G.edges` and a list comprehension like this

```
[
    other_node
    for edge in G.edges()
    for other_node in edge
    if node in edge and other_node != node
]
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks @NicolasMartinez. Very compact and fast.